# jQuery Clone and renaming child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, clone, addclass

I have a DIV Element with an image, some text, a url link to the image and a link to a status of the image

- this status is represented by an icon next to the image
- I use .on("click"..., event to trigger a phpscript that updates the status in thebackground and **returns** new status

This status link has a class that uses a csshook, meaning that the image ID is part of the class name(statusrec41).

Using jQuery I clone the DIV.

```
$clone =  $('#divrec41').clone(true).attr('id', '#divrec42');
```

I then update the URL with the new record ID

```
$clone.find('[href]').each(function(){this.href=this.href.replace(/rec41/g, 'rec42')})
```

Then display at end

```
$clone.appendTo('#imageArea');
```

The part I am lost in is in how to update the class name to reflect the new ID **before** I append the cloned element
Would be nice if I could do a replace all "rec41" to "rec42", but noooo

Comment: you don't need that '#' before 'divrec42' in your .attr() call, or it will be confusing next time you try to query that element (e.g. `$('##divrec42')`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do this ?

```
$(document).find('.rec41').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("rec41");
    $(this).addClass("rec42");
})
```

Comment: Yes, because I believe your clone is not visible unless you add it to the DOM, and that's appendTo may do. Is it a problem?

Comment: Correct, 
I was hoping I could do it before the append. My actual class is a bit more complex than "rec41" and I was hoping there was a way I would not have to rebuild the class name. I will I will end up using addClass/removeClass

Been reading alot about html5 data-js hooks but am not sure I like that option

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in one line:

```
$clone.attr('class', your_classes).appendTo('#imageArea');
```

Comment: There is no way it does not do it unless you are doing it wrong